# Script to count totals from commands and output to screen

Tags: bash

I am looking for assistance in creating a bash script that will run several similar commands, sum up the totals and output that total to the screen. I want to run the following commands:

```
find /var/log/audit -xdev -type f -printf '%i\n' | sort -u | wc -l

find /boot -xdev -type f -printf '%i\n' | sort -u | wc -l

find /home -xdev -type f -printf '%i\n' | sort -u | wc -l
```

And so on. I have a few others. What I am basically doing is counting up all of the files in each mount point on my system, then I need the script to sum up all of the output from each commands "wc -l" and output the grand total to the screen. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Based on all examples given so far, this appears to be an [X-Y Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). You seem to want to count distinct inodes, but you're asking about adding output numbers instead. Which is the real question?

Comment: My understanding is that inodes also include directories, which is why I have decided to use find and pass the -type f. I am just looking for a file count. For example on my system using df --inodes or du -a blah blah my numbers are around 77k whereas these commands come in at about 66k.

Comment: Sure. My point is that this SO question doesn't address any of that. It won't explain that discrepancy as well as a good question on unix.stackexchange.com would. There's probably a very good reason `df` is implemented that way.

Comment: Right. I understand. I have read all of the posts at the unix site for the best approach to counting up files and there are many ways to do this to filter out things you don't want or to get around other problems. For my use case this command I have found to be what I need. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
a=$(find /var/log/audit -xdev -type f -printf '%i\n' | sort -u | wc -l)

b=$(find /boot -xdev -type f -printf '%i\n' | sort -u | wc -l)

c=$(find /home -xdev -type f -printf '%i\n' | sort -u | wc -l)

final=$(($a+$b+$c))

echo $final
```

Answer (score 1):

I would redirect each commands output to a file

```
your_command >> results.txt
```

and sum them up

```
awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' results.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work without naming names, change the `echo n` with your scripts

```
awk '{sum+=$1} END{print "total: "sum}' < <(echo 4; echo 5; echo 6)
```

alternatively if the individual counts are not required you can pass more than one path to find

```
find path1 path2 path3 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good place for [`dc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dc.1.html)

```
{
    for mnt in /var/log/audit /boot /home; do
        find "$mnt" -xdev -type f -printf '%i\n' | sort -u | wc -l
    done
    echo "+"
    echo "+"
    echo "p"
} | dc
```

You need one less "+" than your number of mountpoints.